# Tracking parameters into eBay

Tags: parameters, tracking, ebay-design-templates

I have a shop on eBay and would like to measure how effective my Internet marketing is.
Is it possible to pass parameters into eBay and then be able to use those values?

For example a link from Twitter promoting an item might be
http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/widgets/123456789012?source=twitter

I'm wondering if eBay have reserved parameters such as 'source' above that I could use.

I also send out personalised emails to clients. I'd love to be able to track the source of the sale by splicing & `source=value` onto a link in the email.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Listing Analytics](https://web.archive.org/web/20180428143031/http://pages.ebay.co.uk/help/sell/listing-analytics.html) might achieve the basics of what you are looking for.

To obtain a more comprehensive breakdown, I would propose replacing the default eBay links with redirects stored on your own site (for example: https://mysite.uk?action=ebay_redirect&item=123456789&source=twitter) and then utilising Google Analytics to track the parameters.

Whilst I haven't personally used it, eBay do offer an API to developers from which you may be able to glean even more information on the marketing and performance of your shop.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm not sure it's precisely what I'm after but the Listing Analytics looks very useful so thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe there is a good way of doing this.  You can add analytics tracking codes into your listing template, you can also have links from your other sites that will track the links into eBay.

Sadly what you can't track (that I know of) is the sales and where they came from.  You might be able to tell that 40 people this month went to eBay from your site, or viewed your items, but you can't tell what proportion went on to purchase etc..

If you do find an answer I'd be very interested though!